# Intent in android error

Tags: android, android-intent

Everyone  i'm getting error while using Intent in android. I have a MainActivity from where i call another class called BackgroundWorker so after doing some functions of login i want to go to user page if it is a sucesss.enter code here im attaching my code here Please help

```
package com.example.user.mybookapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText UsernameEt, PasswordEt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    UsernameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
    PasswordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
}

public void OnLogin(View view) {
    String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";


    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type,username,password);
}
```

}

//BackgoundWorker class

```
package com.example.user.mybookapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by user on 15-09-2016.
 */
public  class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>  {
public Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String[] params)
{
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://192.168.4.2/login.php";
    if(type.equals("login"))
    {
        try {
            //Context context = getApplicationContext();
            //Toast t=     Toast.makeText(ctx,"click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            //alertDialog.setTitle("login status");
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream =  httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                result += line;

            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
   return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("login status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
    String s=result.trim();
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
         Intent i =Intent(BackgroundWorker.this,User.class);//Problem


    }

}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

}

Comment: And the problem is???

Comment: Did you lkook in logcat for errors? Have you added an `<activity>` declaration for `User` to your manifest? Is `User` an `Activity`? I could ask a million questions. We don't read minds. Please tell us exactly what you expect to happen, what actually happens and what errors or other messages you see in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i =Intent(context,User.class);
```

This should fix the error, intent should be called using current context.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent i =Intent(context,User.class);
 context.startActivity(i);
```

This will work as BackgroundWorker.this is a non activity reference.

Answer (score 0):

Intent constructor needs a context as first parameter and you are giving it AsyncTask. You are not constructing object of Intent class properly, in other words you have forgotten to write `new` keyword.This is the syntax to create a object:-

```
<Class> <objectName> = new <Class/Subclass>(constructor_params_separated_by_commas);

Intent i =Intent(BackgroundWorker.this,User.class);//Problem
```

change it to

```
Intent i =new Intent(context,User.class);//Problem solved
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Hello harish, thanks for the help but the problem is now when i run the app it says "Unfortunatly the app has stopped"

Comment: Check Android Monitor tab and give me Exception information from log, then i can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,SecondClass.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY","Value");
startActivity(intent);
//here KEY = the identifier of specific value
//on other side of SecondClass Activity. catch this data using 
String res = getIntent().getStringExtra("KEY");
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answers above, first problem is the inappropriate context, second problem is that you are passing wrong arguments in your background worker class while performing background task execution. Your AsyncTask extension:

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

shows that you must pass String in doInBackground method, while in the code above you are trying to get string Array although you have passed String parameters from your main activity i.e

```
protected String doInBackground(String[] params)
```

should be

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
```

Hope that solves the issue.